# I keep getting 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I am new to coding and I have no idea how to use 'floats'.  Could someone please inform me where to use floats in this piece of code so that I will not receive the:

```
TypeError, 'float' object is not callable.
```

my code so far:

```
def problem1_7():
    b1 = input("Enter the length of one of your bases: ")
    b2 = input("Enter the length of one of your bases: ")
    h = input("Enter the height: ")

    area = (1/2)(b1+b2)*h

    print("The area of a trapezoid with bases",b1,"and",b2,"and height      ",h,"is",area)
```

Comment: what operation do you think `(1/2)(b1+b2)*h` is performing?

Comment: Seriously? Where's CSS coming here?

Comment: Also, `b1`, `b2` and `h` are all going to be strings. You'll need to wrap them in `float()` before you treat them as floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `area = (1/2)(b1+b2)*h`.

Python syntax differs from a mathematical, for one, () are used to pass parameters to a method call. However, (1/2) returns a float, hence what is interpreted is a call with the result of b1 + b2 as parameter to (1/2).

You just need to insert `*` in the formula to make it right, i.e. change method invocation to multiplication (which is defined for type float).

Hence, the fixed line would be `area = (1/2)*(b1+b2)*h`.

Another issue, you would notice after fixing this is the actual type of all variables , i.e. `b1`, `b2`, and `h` being strings. To fix that you need to parse them as floats:

```
b1 = float(input("Enter the length of one of your bases: "))
b2 = float(input("Enter the length of one of your bases: "))
h = float(input("Enter the height: "))
```

Python uses [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), hence problem such as those often surface in run time.

Comment: Thanks, I also realized I needed to wrap the variables with floats as well, now it works.